# Proving three float numbers exist, such that Associative Property of Addition is false

Tags: c#, addition, associative

I am looking for three float values such that, 
(A + B) + C != A + (B + C)

The float values are in range of 0.002 and 10 and apparently there are many solutions to this problem. I use the following algorithm to test all values from 0.001 to 10.000 in C#; I started the test 12 minutes ago and it is still running.

```
for (float i = 0.002f; i < 10f; i = i + 0.001f)
{
    for (float j = 0.002f; j < 10f; j = j + 0.001f)
    {
        for (float k = 0.002f; k < 10f; k = k + 0.001f)
        {
            float FirstAnswer = (i + j) + k;
            float SecondAnswer = (j + k) + i;
            if (FirstAnswer != SecondAnswer)
            {
                Console.Write("(" + i.ToString() + " + " + j.ToString() + ") + " + k.ToString() + " = " + FirstAnswer.ToString() + "\n");
                Console.Write("(" + j.ToString() + " + " + k.ToString() + ") + " + i.ToString() + " = " + SecondAnswer.ToString() + "\n\n");
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I ensure all values are always float. I imagine float addition must work differently than regular decimal addition, but I fail to see the connection. Is there a better algorithm to prove the Associative Property of Addition false using float values by finding all values in the given range?

Comment: How does your `if` looks like? Compiler is smart.

Comment: @Sinatr See edit above. As of now 16 minutes has passed and it is STILL running, though no output in the console.

Comment: Do you *need* an algorithm? If not, think about [epsilons](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: @kill4silence Your program is going to run for a while, since you're comparing them like you are, the complexity of your algorithm is O(n^3). So you're comparing 10000 ^ 3 equations. Look into symmetry in algorithms and see if that helps you. I can tell you that this concept is the study goal of your exercise.

Comment: You can see output to know in witch step  you are

Comment: I'd say you should go from `float.MinValue` to `float.MaxValue` (make your step incremented by power, not `+0.001`, but e.g. `*10`). The said effect will appears if you add first too big value to to small and then something. Then order matters.

Comment: @kill4silence Are you looking for just 1 solution? Or for all solutions between the given range

Comment: @Glubus All the solutions between the given range.

Comment: The last question in the post is a bit confusing. You don't really want to prove it. You need to find all solutions in the range. Probably you should edit the post in order to make it clearer.

Comment: @Dmitry Edited for clarity. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Here's something that will blow your mind: Release builds and Debug builds act differently with respect to floating point calculations. Try a release build instead and see what happens. On my system, the release build prints out a load of numbers, and debug one doesn't.

Comment: I note that you chose to use increments of 1 / 1000, a very "decimal" quantity.  Can you make a prediction of what would happen if you used increments of 1 / 1024, a very "binary" quantity, instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are differences between debug and release builds. If I run a DEBUG build of your program, I get no output.

If I run a RELEASE build, I get a lot of output.

If you change your program as follows, you'll get some output even in a debug build. I just compute the values in separate steps, as you will see:

```
for (float i = 0.002f; i < 10f; i = i + 0.001f)
{
    for (float j = 0.002f; j < 10f; j = j + 0.001f)
    {
        for (float k = 0.002f; k < 10f; k = k + 0.001f)
        {
            float FirstAnswer = (i + j);
            FirstAnswer += k;

            float SecondAnswer = (j + k);
            SecondAnswer += i;

            if (FirstAnswer != SecondAnswer)
            {
                Console.Write("(" + i.ToString() + " + " + j.ToString() + ") + " + k.ToString() + " = " + FirstAnswer.ToString() + "\n");
                Console.Write("(" + j.ToString() + " + " + k.ToString() + ") + " + i.ToString() + " = " + SecondAnswer.ToString() + "\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for this discrepancy is that the C# compiler and runtime are allowed at their discretion for **any reason whatsoever** to do **any float or double computation whatsoever** in *more* precision than is called for by the specification. As you note, changing from debug to release mode can cause this discrepancy to occur; in debug mode the compiler and runtime generate code that is more likely to round off values to the required precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to generate all variants of your comparation and check witch scenarious are actually fails without using EPSILON for result comparation you can use NUnit framework and [RangeAttribute](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=range&r=2.5):

```
[Test]
public void TestFloatAddition([Range(0.002f,10f,0.001f] float a,
           [Range(0.002f,10f,0.001f] float b, 
           [Range(0.002f,10f,0.001f] float c)
{
    Assert.AreEquals((a + b) + c, a + (b + c));
}
```

This code will generates test for each `a`, `b` and `c` and you can run it in one session.

Comment: Does this framework detect and avoid symmetry in problems?

Comment: @Glubus no it does not but I think that this detecting will work slower then extra checking of symmetric scenarios.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure OPs problem is not the actual comparing of the floats, but rather the huge amount of equations it has to solve. Have you run that piece of code? Because if it is in fact relatively fast, it's a pretty dope tool. If it does not,  then I don't think your answer solves OPs problem

Comment: There is no big time difference for this code but the profit is that you can run test cases independent.

Comment: So you how does that help OP, you should've used a comment instead of an answer.